# How to remove or hide swatches for specific products?

Tags: magento2, swatches

Some of our products are available in a range of colors and sizes, and other products are only available in one color and one size.

For example:

- A t-shirt might be available in red and blue, sizes XS-XXL (Configurable with multiple simple products)
- A scarf is available in white only, and in one size only (Configurable with one simple product)
- A one-off membership is offered (Configurable with one virtual product)

We use swatches for the selection of sizes and colors in the frontend. The swatches are also shown for those products which are available in only one size and color; the customer is forced to select a color and size.

How can I hide swatches for products that are available in only one size and color, and ensure that the customer can add them into the shopping cart without any disruptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use simple products in place of configurable products for those products which are available in only one variation.

Simple products don't have swatches for the front end.

Please let me know if it makes sense for you.

Comment: It is in general a good idea, Mohit - thank you for your answer. I upvote it, because it is correct. Unfortunately, all our processes are adapted for a workflow which only allows for the combination of configurables with simples/virtuals. This is, unfortunately, a factor beyond my control.